# Turn interface generic based on Zod schema

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics, zod

I've got this interface `I`:

```
import { z } from "zod";

const schema = z.object({
  name: z.string(),
});

type S = z.infer<typeof schema>;

interface I {
  process: (obj: S) => object;
  schema: z.ZodSchema;
}
```

It contains a Zod schema and a function to process the validated results. (Let's assume I've got good reasons not to do the validation in the `process` function.)

I'd like to turn this into an interface which based on a Zod schema makes sure the `schema` contains said schema, and that `process` takes an `obj` in argument of the schema TypeScript type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `z.ZodSchema` is a generic class where you can define the type of the schema you want.

Basically, you should just refactor your interface to the following:

```
interface I<T> {
  process: (obj: T) => object;
  schema: z.ZodSchema<T>;
}
```

Now `I.schema` accepts a `z.ZodSchema` with a given type, the same that use the `I.process` function.

Check [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgLzgXzgMyhEcBEyEAJvgNwBQFAxhAHYDO8D1AFgKYgCGcAvCgDoIAIwBW7ajAAUCCnDh0uIdgC5BTKMDoBzKQEoANBTR7KFGAE8w7OAGU+grZnZQAPJesRMcFh24A+My0YF0wuahsASUQ5ODAcCIYGNSkRUTVbPT5-ODSJGEp5X04uNWQBAC0SWzYSyjQqWkZ4EKYARjVo-ll5eIhE5LgZBSUbE2yhpFK4NvRDWOLuYzMAehW4LgYfAFdtbXYmdmI4LTgYDg3GAHcXKmDQ8KiAJlcAFRyeuISDwdSxNVeWV4OTykkKPlq3DKlWqkK4b0Cxka9CYZwOMCenRethy3VifQGKSQimUcwmw2msxMRnkazgAD0APwLOFGNCUIA)

Comment: Thank you! But maybe you could add a usage example? I am experiencing some problems in how to use it. [Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgLzgXzgMyhEcBEyEAJvgNwBQFAxhAHYDO8D1AFgKYgCGcAvCgDoIAIwBW7ajAAUCCnDh0uIdgC5BTKMDoBzKQEoANBTR7KFGAE8w7OAGU+grZnZQAPJesRMcFh24A+My0YF0wuahsASUQ5ODAcCIYGNSkRUTVbPT5-ODSJGEp5X04uNWQBAC0SWzYSyjQqWkZ4EKYARjVo-ll5eIhE5LgZBSUbE2yhpFK4NvRDWOLuYzMAehW4LgYfAFdtbXYmdmI4LTgYDg3GAHcXKmDQ8KiAJlcAFRyeuISDwdSxNVeWV4OTykkKPlq3DKlWqkK4b0Cxka9CYZwOMCenReAHUABIAQVeAH1XgB5InYgBKkVeAFEibjaZTaTlurE+gMUkhFMo5hNhtNZiYjEU4csKEA)

Comment: @KentLarsson sorry for the late response, I have updated my answer, please let me know if you still miss something.

Comment: @NullIndr Thanks, then I got it! I guess the "Stack Overflow" way would be to put the example into the answer, in the playground disappears. But that's up to you! Thanks for your help!

Comment: Zod has documentation on [Writing generic functions](https://zod.dev/?id=writing-generic-functions), but doesn't mention `ZodSchema`. Thanks

Comment: @BenButterworth `ZodSchema` is actually just an alias for [`ZodType`](https://github.com/colinhacks/zod/blob/5e23b4fae4715c7391f9ceb4369421a034851b4c/src/types.ts#L4804)